# kobuki malformed subpayload

Tags: kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I use ros ingido over ubuntu 14.04 LTS..
In the begining everything was fine...
But recently i started to get "Kobuki "malformed subpayload" error when i plug turtlebot and kinect v2 into usb 3.0 port  my laptop (which is Lenovo t430) and launch turtlebot minimal bring-up.. after a while this error show up and repeats itself..
Did anyone know about that error?and what about the solution..
thank you
yselim

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262557/kobuki-malformed-subpayload/) by [yselim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30521/yselim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like a serial port desync / data corruption.

Does the same problem occur if you don't plug in the Kinect?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yselim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30521/yselim/) on 2017-05-26**:
I tried to plug in kobuki on virtual machine  using another laptop with and without kinect and there is no error no error.
So How can i solve that problem if it's about ports??

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-26**:
Try to use one of the USB2 ports on your laptop for the Kobuki, and use the USB3 for the Kinect only.

**Comment by [yselim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30521/yselim/) on 2017-05-26**:
let me try it..should i just plug them different ports or should i set ports using some kind of command line command?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-26**:
Just use different ports. The USB3 ones should be blue(-ish) on the inside. USB2 is black.

**Comment by [yselim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30521/yselim/) on 2017-05-27**:
I tried; kinect to the 3.0 and turtlebot to the 2.0 port
but again same error.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-27**:
Try all the ports that you have. There is a chance that if you connect things to different controllers it'll work. But no guarantees. The Kinect v2 uses a huge amount of bandwidth, so different controllers will mean less interference.

All of this assuming that this is the problem, of course.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-27**:\

> I tried to plug in kobuki on virtual machine using another laptop with and without kinect and there is no error no error

btw: are you running everything in a VM, or was that just for this test?

Also: please try to use just the Kobuki in your t430. Not in another laptop.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-27**:
If it's just the T430 btw then I would try and find out if you changed anything lately. Updates to your Linux kernel? Settings you changed?

**Comment by [yselim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30521/yselim/) on 2017-05-27**:
In the begining there was no error. Gvdhoom i thougt that too,maybe some updates occured that error so i re-installed clean 14.04 and didnt update or upgrade anything. But error stil there. In my opinion it seems like it's all about usb ports. As u mentioned kinect uses huge bandwith.but solution?